# PHP & MySql query with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php version:

```
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19
```

and this php string:

```
$l_sDesc = "It doesn' t contain any dangerous substances";
```

If i try to make a query with db_query (Drupal) i get an error due to the apostrophe;

```
db_query("UPDATE mytable SET description= '$l_sDesc' where id = $id");
```

I've tried to use mysql_real_escape_string() but i get an empty string:

```
$l_sDesc = mysql_real_escape_string($l_sDesc);  //i have an empty string as result
```

What's the problem?

Comment: In conjunction with `mysql_real_escape_string()` use `stripslashes()`

Comment: how? i've tried but doesn't work

Comment: Why is everyone advocating deprecated functions?

Comment: I deleted my answer since you don't want to show me how you're doing your insert. (voted to close) Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal use another DB Wrapper. Normally you can create prepared statements.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7

Here is a correct example. If you use the correct prepared statements your input will be filtered.

Otherwise use `stripslashes()`.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Tom, you need to "prepare" the string for SQL before you actually run the statement.

Try the PHP function mysql_real_escape_string on your strings before you actually use them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `$l_sDesc = htmlspecialchars($l_sDesc);`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is only appropriate for escaping for output to HTML, not for output into an SQL query.

Comment: @JanKrüger, htmlspecialchars will convert `'` into `&quote;` and will prevent SQL errors and security holes :)